# how to wait for grandchild of a process to terminate in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, subprocess, batch-processing

I have a python script that starts a subprocess by connecting to a batchscript. The way it works is, Python script triggers batchscript and batchscript triggers Java code. After Java code triggers, the process is no longer the python script's child.

Is there any way to tell python script or to batchscript to wait for the Java code to terminate? I want to make python script wait until all grandchildren are terminated.

The way it currently works is: there is a waitString that tells to batchscript to wait, if in a list of accounts(a/b/c/d), until d's grandchildren is terminated. It does not wait for c or b to finish. 
My current code:

```
try:    
    p = Popen([batchCommand, account_list, waitString], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

except OSError as e:
    print "OSError > ",e.errno 
    print "OSError > ",e.strerror 
output , errors = p.communicate()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "batchscript" is too generic, what specific language/shell are you talking about?

Comment: you can try `op, err = p.communicate()` if either of your scripts are blocking. or you can also work with `p.wait()` or `p.poll()` to check for the status of the  subprocess , refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll and https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: I just edited the code to include p.communicate(), however that doesn't solve my problem. Once batchscript is triggered subprocess becomes python scripts grandchild. I want to check if that grand child is terminated. Batchscript is in Windows. @martineau

Comment: if python waits for the batchscript and it waits for the java process then python effectively waits for java process. If java process inherits stdout, stderr from the batchscript then `.communicate()` waits for the java process even if the batchscript doesn't wait for the java process. How do you run the java process? Why the batchscript doesn't wait for the java process?

Comment: The batch file code is what you need to modify. How is the Java application started from within the batch file? If you are using command `start` without parameter `/wait`, the Java application is executed in a new command process and therefore the batch process started from within Python script immediately continues.